# LARAVEL : Route issue after hosting change

Tags: php, laravel

I change the hosting on our website but after the change the htacess has been gone and I copied the htaccess into the new one now the problem is the routing does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try to change PHP version to the new one and after that put the old version 
When you change PHP version it automatically generates htaccess file in your hosting